# How to call one function from another function in same javascript file in lightning web component

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

If  there are two javascript methods A() and B() in same LWC component, is it possible to call method B() from A() where Function A() gets called with click of button? If not what can be the possible workaround for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use `this` to access other methods:

```
export default class CMD extends LightningElement {
  A() {
    this.B();
  }
  B() {
    // do something //
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a parameter. Use this

```
export default class CMD extends LightningElement {
A() {
  var addition = 5+5;
    this.B(addition);
  }
  B(add) {
    console.log('Addition is : '+add);
  }
}
```